# DatGrid binding for list of MenuItem in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, wpfdatagrid, model-binding

I am using a DataGrid in WPF for populating MenuItems.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
   <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Menu Items" Binding="{Binding Path=MenuItem.Name}" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I am populating the `DataGrid.DataContext` like this

```
List<MenuItem> lst = GetValues();
dataGrid1.DataContext = lst;
```

The list appears empty on the `Datagrid` because the Binding is not working.
`Binding="{Binding Path=MenuItem.Name}` this needs to be changed so that I can display the name from the Name property when the menuitems are displayed in the DataGrid.

Comment: Don't you just want `Binding="{Binding Name}"`?

Comment: Try binding DataGridTextColumn without path (Binding="{Binding}") same way like DataGrid  itemsource. If it displays some thing them you can find the problem easily.. if it doesn't displays anything they problem is in ItemsSource

Comment: My bad, yes thats just what I wanted, `Binding="{Binding Name}"` works fine,Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Binding="{Binding Name}"` works fine. Thanks to @Charleh